# Magento 2: Checkout Page Remove Last Name and Merge Last Name field value to First Name

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer

On the checkout page, I want to remove the Last Name field and Merge the Last Name field value with the First Name field.

I have checked Magento Stack Exchange answer, but it removes the field from Registration and edit address page.

[image]

Comment: in magento 2 Last name is required field so if you want merge First name to Last Name you can hide Last name field and use js to fill Last Name.

Comment: @Kushal did you complete this?

Answer (score 0):

> app/code/[CompanyName]/[PackageName]/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[CompanyName]_[PackageName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> app/code/[CompanyName]/[PackageName]/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[CompanyName]_[PackageName]" setup_version="1.0.3"/>
</config>
```

> app/code/[CompanyName]/[PackageName]/Setup/UpgradeSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace [CompanyName]\[PackageName]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeSchemaInterface;

class UpgradeSchema implements UpgradeSchemaInterface
{
    public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<=')) {
            $setup->startSetup();
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_entity'),
                'lastname_bk',
                ['type'    => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => 0,
                    'comment'  => 'Last name field backup'
                ]
            );
            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('customer_address_entity'),
                'lastname_bk',
                ['type'    => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => 0,
                    'comment'  => 'Last name field backup'
                ]
            );
            $setup->endSetup();
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/[CompanyName]/[PackageName]/Setup/UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace [CompanyName]\[PackageName]\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection;

class UpgradeData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface
{
    private $customerSetupFactory;
    protected $resourceConnection;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        ResourceConnection $resourceConnection
    )
    {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->resourceConnection = $resourceConnection;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
                            ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.3', '<=')) {
            $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
            $customerSetup->updateAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'lastname', 'is_required', 0);
            $entityAttributes = [
                'customer_address' => [
                    'lastname' => [
                        'is_required' => 0,
                        'is_visible' => 0,
                    ],
                ],
            ];
            $customerSetup->upgradeAttributes($entityAttributes);

            $tableName = $this->getTableName('customer_entity');
            $sql = "update $tableName set lastname_bk = lastname";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);
            $sql = "update $tableName set firstname = concat( firstname, ' ', lastname)";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);
            $sql = "update $tableName set lastname = NULL";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);

            $tableName = $this->getTableName('customer_address_entity');
            $sql = "update $tableName set lastname_bk = lastname";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);
            $sql = "update $tableName set firstname = concat( firstname, ' ', lastname)";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);
            $sql = "update $tableName set lastname = ''";
            $this->resourceConnection->getConnection()->query($sql);

        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }

    public function getTablename($tableName)
    {
        /* Create Connection */
        $connection  = $this->resourceConnection->getConnection();
        $tableName   = $connection->getTableName($tableName);
        return $tableName;
    }
}
```